# ruby equal method always returns parameter value instead of returned value

Tags: ruby

My issue is that on assignment my value can be modified, but the returned value by `#bar=` will not be the one of my implicit return and it will instead be the `value` parameter.

```
class Foo
  def bar=(value)
    @bar = "these not the droids you are looking for"
  end

  def bar
    @bar
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
puts foo.bar = 42 # 42
puts foo.bar # "these not the droids you are looking for"
```

I'd like my last line to print `"these not the droids you are looking for"` instead of `42`. Is that possible?

Comment: From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Return+Values): _"Note that for assignment methods the return value will be ignored when using the assignment syntax. Instead, the argument will be returned"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that possible?

Nope, that's how assignment operator is treated in ruby. You can switch from `bar=` to, say, `set_bar`. This now is just an ordinary method and will not get its return value ignored in an assignment operation (because it can't be used there).

Or you can do something like `foo.send("bar=", 42)`, but please don't.